# How to drop a function with Hibernate/JDBC?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jdbc, h2

I'm trying to run this query

```
drop FUNCTION IF EXISTS time_factor;
```

I want to run it through the Hibernate session with either `createSQLQuery()` or `doWork()`.
Like this:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(query).executeUpdate();
```

or

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().doWork(new Work() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            connection.prepareStatement(query).executeUpdate();
        }
});
```

This is what I get:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "DROP FUNCTION[*] IF EXISTS TIME_FACTOR; "; expected "TABLE, INDEX, USER, SEQUENCE, CONSTANT, TRIGGER, VIEW, ROLE, ALIAS, SCHEMA, ALL, DOMAIN, TYPE, DATATYPE, AGGREGATE";
```

Does this mean that I can't drop functions through JDBC/Hibernate ?

Also if someone knows a way I can run it I'd be really grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not JDBC/Hibernate that doesn't support `DROP FUNCTION` but H2 Database.

You can look here for the supported SQL grammar:
http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html

If you are looking to create and drop functions with H2, look for `ALIAS`.
You can create Java function aliases with `CREATE ALIAS` and drop them with `DROP ALIAS`:

```
CREATE ALIAS MY_SQRT FOR "java.lang.Math.sqrt";

DROP ALIAS IF EXISTS MY_SQRT;
```